# how to programmatically create dump file using pure C language?

Tags: c, dump, crash-dumps, minidump

I need to create a dump file for a customer program written in C.

I saw that there is a minidump for windows, is it working only on C++ ?

Is there any other solution for C language?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this excellent tutorial: http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/effminidumps.html . It uses Win32 API `MiniDumpWriteDump`, so its pure C.